# How can I make the animation of a circle continous with hovering like this gif in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js. this is the animation of a circle that I like a lot. It is something like an infinite animation.

[image]

I would like to copy this animation to generate it in d3.js, but I think my knowledge is insufficient, this code is the closest I have been able to copy the animation.

Then my idea is that I can have a mouse hover effect as you can see in the image. How can I do it? thank you very much.

this is my code and this is my current result:

[image]

```
var width = document.getElementById('circles').offsetWidth-70;
  var height =(width/2)+100;     
  var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["yellow","orange","red"])
    .domain([0,60]);

  var data = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60];

  var svg = d3.select("#circles").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width+"px")
      .attr("height", height+"px");

  //circle orange
  svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",80)
  .attr("cy",80)
  .attr("r",30)
   .attr("fill","orange")
  .style("stroke-width","1")
  .style("stroke","orange")    
  .on('mouseover', function(){
    d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",32)
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(){
    d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",30)
  })

  //circle yellow
   svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",80)
  .attr("cy",80)
  .attr("r",22)
  .attr("fill","yellow")
  .style("stroke-width","1")
  .style("stroke","yellow")
  .style("opacity","0.9")    

  .on('mouseover', function(){
    d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",24).style("opacity","1")  
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(){
    d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",22).style("opacity","0.9")
  })      

     var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r",function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("transform","translate(80,80)")
    .attr("fill","none")
    .style("stroke-width","1")
    .style("stroke",function(d) { return scale(d) });  

  function transition() {
    // Update data, max d is 60:
    data = data.map(function(d) { return d == 60 ? 0 : d + 10});

    var i = 0;
    // Grow circles
    circles
       .data(data)
       .filter(function(d) { return d > 0 })
       .transition()
       //.ease(d3.easeLinear)
       .ease("linear")//set the ease here
       .attr("r", function(d) { return d; })
       .style("stroke", function(d) { return scale(d) })
       .style("opacity",function(d) { return d == 60 ? 0 : 1 }) 
       .duration(1000)
       //.on("end",function(){if(++i==circles.size()-1) { transition(); } });
        .each("end", function (d,i) {
          //.on("end", function (d,i) {
           if(++i==circles.size()-1) { transition(); } 
        });

    // Reset circles where r == 0
    circles
      .filter(function(d) { return d == 0 })
      .attr("r", 0)
      .style("opacity",1)
      .style("stroke",function(d) { return scale(d); });

  }
  transition();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kz2tbxoS9lsfy2oMDzhY?p=preview

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45354816/7106086)?

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks to you I was able to improve my code, I am getting closer to what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case to learn **d3.transition** functionality.
Like @AndrewReid's reference and your code already there for your expected effect.

In your code(if I understand correctly), you directly produce the emanating effect with data updating the circle radius and control each circle's life cycle directly with selection group number.

Indeed, you can directly use **d3.transition property** to control the circle transition **life cycle** to produce emananting effect.

**Here some reading material for d3.transition life cycle**:

1. [A Life of a transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#the-life-of-a-transition)
2. [Working with Transition](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/)

**Here's my code**:
In my implementation, I use data to decide the emananting circle number and 
use transition.on to listen each transition cycle done and reset the property.

```
//DOM.svg is the syntax in observablhq, in browser, replace with your way
const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(250,250));

const data = Array.from(Array(CircleNumber).keys());

// use this emanating function to control the execution cycles
function emananting(num){

        svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
         .transition() 
         .duration((d,i)=>{
          return 2500;
        })  // duration to control each circle emananting duration
         .delay((d,i)=>{
          return i*500; 
          }) // delay to control between each circle's space
         .attr('opacity',0)
         .attr('r',50)
         .on('end',(d,i,g)=>{
            // after each transition end, trigger these codes
            d3.select(g[i])
              .attr('r', 10)
              .attr('opacity',1);
               // control flow from listening to the last transition    done!
               // remove the num < 10 condition , it will be infinite
               if (i===5 && num < 2){
                    console.log(num);
                    emananting(num+1);

                }
            });
 }
 // Here create the center circle body
 svg.append('circle')
 .classed('CircleBody',true)
 .attr('r',10)
 .attr('stroke','yellow')
 .attr('fill','orange')
 .attr('opacity',1)
 .attr('cx',125)
 .attr('cy',125);

// Here create the emanting circle
svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class','emanting')
            .attr('id', (d,i)=>{
                return 'number' + i;
                            })
            .attr('r',10)
            .attr('stroke','orange')
            .attr('fill','none')
            .attr('opacity',1)
            .attr('cx',125)
            .attr('cy',125);
 // control flow 
 emananting(0);
```

Here some demo on @observablehq
https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/demo-how-can-i-make-the-animation-of-a-circle-continous-with-h

Comment: thanks for your time. but, something happens with your example or with the page. the consumption of RAM is very high, it blocks my browser.

Comment: sorry, now I'm fixing the problems

Comment: it fixed now, but I think these also arouse another issue when implementation of infinite animation, one should consider the RAM or other performance issue ><

Comment: https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/demo-how-can-i-make-the-animation-of-a-circle-continous-with-h

Comment: thank you very much, I wanted to do it just like the gif, I have updated my question now, you can see the current result and I think with your help I am almost at the same point. animated circles from the beginning are active.

Comment: can you help me please to have the gif like the first image?

Comment: @yavg I update the demo https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/demo-how-can-i-make-the-animation-of-a-circle-continous-with-h, does it near what you expected? I think I just add a radial gradient effect on the outer  circle. (I use the d3.js v5 version, so some syntax is changed now, ex d3.ease )

Comment: wow! It's just what I want. I'm not very good at d3.js and I only drive v3. I will try to convert it to the v3 version. Is it possible to have the animation of infinite continuous circles? thank you very much friend!

Comment: great man, can you help me please with a similar question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49261253/how-can-i-convert-this-code-that-is-in-d3-v5-to-d3-v3-it-is-an-animation-of-a-c

Comment: Can you convert your code to my pnlkr please? I am not able to adapt it
 :(

Comment: @yavg Here is the conversion to v3 https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/v3-version-demo-how-can-i-make-the-animation-of-a-circle-conti I'm not familiar with d3.v3, because I was learning it from v4.

Comment: @yavg I also use generator to let it be infinite without overloading!

Comment: I want to use your code, but I am unable to replicate your code in a plnkr, I get some errors. Can you please update my plnkr with your code? I would greatly appreciate it