# Create an Animated Pulsing Circle with D3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I know that similar questions have been asked before here on stackoverflow, but I have fairly specific requirements.  I'm trying to generate a pulsing dot for a D3 chart.

I modified some code on codepen.io and came up with [this](https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/BaaqKpO?editors=1000).

**How would I do the same thing using a D3 transition() rather than the (cheesy) CSS classes?**

Something more along the lines of:

```
circle = circle.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attr("stroke-width", 20)
.attr("r", 10)
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
.attr("r", 200)
.ease('sine')
.each("end", repeat);
```

Feel free to fork my sample pen.

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45349849/7106086) approach with d3 transitions suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [example](https://gist.github.com/whityiu/fb9f138a4a91032fa9ec) on GitHub by [whityiu](https://gist.github.com/whityiu)

Note that this is using d3 version 3.

I have adapted that code to produce something like you are after in the fiddle below.

```
var width = 500,
    height = 450,
    radius = 2.5,
    dotFill = "#700f44",
    outlineColor = "#700f44",
    pulseLineColor = "#e61b8a",
    bgColor = "#000",
    pulseAnimationIntervalId;

var nodesArray = [{
    "x": 100,
    "y": 100
}];
// Set up the SVG display area
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("fill", bgColor)
    .classed('visual-area', true);

var bgRect = d3.select("svg").append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var linkSet = null,
    nodeSet = null;

// Create data object sets
nodeSet = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodesArray)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on('click', function() {
        // Clear the pulse animation
        clearInterval(pulseAnimationIntervalId);
    });

// Draw outlines
nodeSet.append("circle")
    .classed("outline pulse", true)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("fill", 'none')
    .attr("stroke", pulseLineColor)
    .attr("r", radius);

// Draw nodes on top of outlines
nodeSet.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("fill", dotFill)
    .attr("stroke", outlineColor)
    .attr("r", radius);

// Set pulse animation on interval
pulseAnimationIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var times = 100,
        distance = 8,
        duration = 1000;
    var outlines = svg.selectAll(".pulse");

    // Function to handle one pulse animation
    function repeat(iteration) {
        if (iteration < times) {
            outlines.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .each("start", function() {
                    d3.select(".outline").attr("r", radius).attr("stroke", pulseLineColor);
                })
                .attrTween("r", function() {
                    return d3.interpolate(radius, radius + distance);
                })
                .styleTween("stroke", function() {
                    return d3.interpolate(pulseLineColor, bgColor);
                })
                .each("end", function() {
                    repeat(iteration + 1);
                });
        }
    }

    if (!outlines.empty()) {
        repeat(0);
    }
}, 6000);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41ae2xc5/)

Comment: I actually had that code open in a browser tab.  I hadn't tried it yet.  It was not far off from what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for modding it for me.  It looks great!